# Hide and show divs on basis of price and category checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am having a `div` arrangement in which I am defining data attributes. Like I'm displaying a product list in a `div` with data attributes, namely `data-category` and `data-price`. I want to hide and show `div`s on basis of selection by checkboxes of category and price. Html structure is as follows:

```
<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="1000">shoe1</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="1200">shirt1</div><br />

<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="2000">shoe2</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shoes" data-price="800">shoe3</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="1300">shirt2</div><br />
<div class="content" data-category="shirts" data-price="800">shirt3</div><br />

<input type="checkbox" class="category" category="shoes" id="shoes">shoes
<input type="checkbox" class="category" category="shirts" id="shirts">shirts
```

For category, I have kept checkboxes, but for price, I need to use range jquery slider I guess, but I'm unable to use that filter. Basically if you select a category from checkbox lets say shoes, then `div`s only with shoes should get displayed; and then if you filter the results with price some starting and ending limit it should show shoes category `div`s falling in that specific range. Not out of range.

For example:- we selected shoes checkbox, it should show shoe divs; then if we select range as 1000-2000, then it should show `shoe1` and `shoe2` and not `shoe3`. Please help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since "category" is not a valid attribute name in html, you should use something else instead. In this case, it would be natural to just use the id directly, as this is the values you need anyway:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="category" id="shoes">shoes
<input type="checkbox" class="category" id="shirts">shirts
```

For range, you could have something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="range" value="0-9000" checked>All
<input type="radio" name="range" value="0-999">0-1000
<input type="radio" name="range" value="1000-2000">1000-2000
```

Then in the javascript:

```
$("input.category").prop("checked", true).change(function (e) {
    //Trigger change event on active price range item where the filter is applied
    $("input[name=range]:checked").trigger("change");
});
$("input[name=range]").change(function (e) {
    var toggle = this.checked;
    var range = this.value.split('-');
    var rangeFrom = parseInt(range[0]);
    var rangeTo = parseInt(range[1]);
    // If all category checkboxes are off we will ignore category filter
    var allOff = ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0);
    $(".content[data-price]").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // Check if category is active
        var active = allOff || $("#" + $this.data("category")).prop("checked");
        // Get price as number
        var price = parseFloat($this.data('price'));
        // Toggle visibility based on category and price range
        $this.toggle(price >= rangeFrom && price <= rangeTo && active );
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks good, except i would add `$(".category").prop("checked", true);` to it. Because it looks weird making them unchecked by default.

Comment: ya.thats perfectly fine.some advises from ur side@awe and @Deja Vu.if we have a new data attribute say Brand.Then if we want to filter it out.Like u checked category as shirt and then u select some brand also,then u choose price.then how to do filteration.Secondly,In place of checkboxes for price.how to do it with price range slider..?Thanks

Comment: It might be an idea to move out the filter code in a separate function, and then call the same filter function from all different type of filter selections. This way you ensure that the correct filter is applied in all cases. You use the same approach to filter on other values. The important is to scan through all the items with `$(".content[data-price]").each` and read current state of all the filter controls you need to use. `$this` represents one content item in the each loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot @awe for your valuable info.Can you please give me one example of category checkbox with price range slider function.Whenever you are free,otherwise i will try to use this one.

Comment: You can try to figure it out yourself. I am not familiar with the slider control, but the method should be similar. Just read the slider values into `rangeFrom` and `rangeTo`, and then use the same approach.

Comment: @user3467631 I'm really not experienced in JS or JQuery though, but maybe this can help you out? http://jsfiddle.net/pw57S/ . Else, just ignore what i just made

Comment: @awe-When range function ,we are checking tht which ever name checkboxes are checked.tht only it will display.Can it be changed to other way sir,that if all checkboxes are unchecked then all records should be displayed?please help me sir if it can be done.i tried but was unable in doing that....

Comment: `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length` will return `0` if all checkboxes are not checked. Then you can use that to display all content like this: `if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length===0) $(".content").show();`

Comment: See the `allOff` I just added. Category is active if all checkboxes are off.